# How to play video from firebase Storage using video_player flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-storage, video-player

I have a video_player which played a video from network(VideoPlayerController.network(
https://...mp4)) and It’s working fine. But I want to take it to another step by playing a video that I get from a snapShot (StreamBuilder) as a video file(ex. 8296971978270266602.mp4) and download it by `storage.ref('videos/$videoFile').getDownloadURL();` *For me to get a link Url of course.* Then I want to put the Url that I get from *DownloadURL* in the VideoPlayer so I can play the video. Please take a look at the code then you’ll understand on what I am trying to achieve.

**code:**

```
final FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
late Future<void> initializeVideoPlayerFuture;
VideoPlayerController? _videoPlayerController;

 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.network(
      'https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/bee.mp4',
    );
    initializeVideoPlayerFuture = _videoPlayerController!.initialize();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _videoPlayerController!.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

             //My StreamBuilder to get snapShot from FB fireStore
             StreamBuilder(
              stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection("groups")
                  .doc(groupId)
                  .snapshots(),
              builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {                
              var videoFile = snapshot.data?["videoFile"];

//ListView that I want to display all the video
  ListView.builder(
       itemCount: videoFile.length,
       shrinkWrap: true,
       itemBuilder: (context, index) {
       
        return FutureBuilder(
                future: initializeVideoPlayerFuture,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                    return AspectRatio(aspectRatio: _videoPlayerController!
                            .value.aspectRatio,
                       child: VideoPlayer(_videoPlayerController!
                          ),
                       );
                      } else {
                return const Center(
                              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                             );
                           }},
                        );

//Download the videoFile from Fb storage(Get the url and play it in the video_player)
  Future<String> downloadVideoURL(String videoFile) async {
    try {
      String downloadURL =
          await storage.ref('videos/$videoFile').getDownloadURL();
      setState(() {
        videoUrl = downloadURL;
      });
      // ignore: avoid_print
      print(downloadURL);
      return downloadURL;
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      // ignore: avoid_print
      print(e);
    }
    return downloadURL(videoFile);
  }
```

**Images:**

[image]

[image]

To summary: As you can see in the code I only play a video by manually putting the Link to that video. But what I want is to put the videoUrl link that I get from downloadVideoUrl. And display all the video as a ListView. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a separate widget for video player and call that widget inside your stream builder as following.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

class VideoPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const VideoPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<VideoPage> createState() => _VideoPageState();
}

class _VideoPageState extends State<VideoPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("groups")
          .doc('groupId')
          .snapshots(),
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
        /// Your code to show the error or loading according to snapshot state
        var videoFile = snapshot.data?["videoFile"];
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: videoFile.length,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
            return VideoPlayerWidget(name: videoFile[index]);
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class VideoPlayerWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const VideoPlayerWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.name,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String name;

  @override
  State<VideoPlayerWidget> createState() => _VideoPlayerWidgetState();
}

  class _VideoPlayerWidgetState extends State<VideoPlayerWidget> {
  VideoPlayerController? _videoPlayerController;
  var _isLoading = true;
late Future<void> initializeVideoPlayerFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initPlayer();
  }

  void _initPlayer() async {
    final _url = await downloadVideoURL(widget.name);
    _videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.network(_url);
    initializeVideoPlayerFuture = _videoPlayerController!.initialize();
    _isLoading = false;
    setState(() {});
  }

  Future<String> downloadVideoURL(String videoFile) async {
    try {
      String downloadURL =
          await storage.ref('videos/$videoFile').getDownloadURL();
      // ignore: avoid_print
      print(downloadURL);
      return downloadURL;
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      // ignore: avoid_print
      print(e);
    }
    return '';
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if(_isLoading) {
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    }
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: initializeVideoPlayerFuture,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          return AspectRatio(
            aspectRatio: _videoPlayerController!.value.aspectRatio,
            child: VideoPlayer(_videoPlayerController!),
          );
        } else {
          return const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I can’t see your  `initializeVideoPlayerFuture` in the code so it says: `Undefined name 'initializeVideoPlayerFuture'.` can you try to fine the mistake?

Comment: I have update my code in case you confused where the `initializeVideoPlayerFuture `is from